# What is the best way to clean a Maven project in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

What is the best way to clean a Maven project in Jenkins?

1. I have tried mvn clean install inside 'Goals and options' any ideas?
2. Is there an addon which is more suitable for the job
3. I need to clean the project before every test execution, in turn a new report will be generated which contains the latest details about all tests which were executed

thanks for yoru help

Comment: Do you mind to tell us why exactly why maven clean plugin wasn't working for you? As far as I know you're able to define phases when you want it to run and folders to clean.

Comment: @Mikhail thanks for the reply, im just puzzled on what code to add for example mvn clean test and where to add into jenkins?

Comment: well basically command: mvn clean test - means that you want to use clean plugin before performing test, also you need to manage what do you want to clean using relative path and including params, more information you may find in here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/examples/delete_additional_files.html - let us know if it won't satisfy your needs.

Comment: Please remove the selenium and webdriver tags - they have nothing to do with your question.

Comment: @Phil_P85 better create a Free Style project and inside the the execute shell command provide the shell or batch command based on OS you are using. if mvn clean is not able o delete some folder, you can write command to delete it manually.